# How to add a directory to SQL*Plus include path?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I would like to add a directory D:\pl-sql to the include path of SQL*Plus so I can then work with files in that directory like, for example, edit them with this command:

```
EDIT hello.sql
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORACLE_PATH is the variable you are looking for. (on Unix) and SQLPATH (for windows)

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b12170/ch3.htm#i1052303

This link explains how you can add to the registry entry for windows..

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b12170/ch3.htm#i1133354

Comment: There is no HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE registry on my machine. I have Database 10g Express Edition installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the habit of creating shortcuts to sqlplusw.exe in my script folders. Edit the shortcut properties to remove anything from the "Start in" field. I can even add the login info on the command line ("Target") so that I can connect instantly with a double-click.

Comment: The "Start In" field may just be the directory which your applications reads as current directory. So, if you fill in the "Start In" field correctly, you could create the shortcut ANYWHERE, because in that case the location of the shortcut is non-relevant. That's just the opposite solution.

Comment: Of course. But leaving it blank means that I can copy my shortcut to any folder containing SQL scripts; and it will still work even if the path is changed. Much more convenient.